# How to write xpath or css for background-image value

Tags: xpath, css-selectors

I wanted to write Xpath or css for

```
<div class="img"style="background-image:url(//cdn.shopify.com/shopifycloud/shopify/assets/no-image-2048-5e88c1b20e087fb7bbe9a3771824e743c244f437e4f8ba93bbf7b11b53f7824c_560x.gif);"></div>
```

Comment: Welcome to the community. Are you able to provide more about the DOM structure? Often times just looking at one element in the DOM tree isn't enough to create an xpath or css element locator. Have you tried using the "copy xpath" or "copy selector" in Chrome's dev tools?

Answer (score 1):

```
div[style^=background-image]
```

use above css locator, which checks for div tag element with style property starting with background-image

you can also use xpath:

```
//div[starts-with(@style, 'background-image')]
```